# Is there a way to unwrap response when using trpc express adapter?

Tags: javascript, express, trpc.io, trpc

I have been using trpc [enter link description here][1]
And what I have seen is it always wraps the response inside result.data object. so all endpoints respond with

```
{result : {data:{ original_response : []} }
```

Is there a way to unwrap the result, and respond with original result? And is it possible to do this for a specific endpoint alone?

Went through its documentation and some other resources, but couldnt find any lead. any help or tip appreciated.